# Bash parameter substitution and expansion in one go

Tags: bash

Is an expression like

```
a=(asd fgh ijk); b=${a[@]:1:${#a[@]}^};
```

somehow writable in bash?

I would expect it to capitalize the first letter of each word after the first one.

(I know how to do it in multiple expressions, but I would like to know how to do it by combining the two features (expansion and substitution), if possible...)

Comment: Do you mean: to get `asd Fgh Ijk` ?

Comment: @sorontar Exactly.

Comment: Yes, but in addition to that, I would like to skip the first word (in the same expression).. Is it possible?

Comment: Oh, too bad.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way if the first element is the only one to start with that character:

```
$ a=(asd fgh ijk)
$ echo "${a[@]^[!${a:0:1}]}"
asd Fgh Ijk
```

This extracts the very first character of the first element, then excludes that character from being uppercased; `[!${a:0:1}]` expands to `[!a]`, which matches only `f` and `i` as the first characters of their elements.

It fails if multiple elements start with the same character, though:

```
$ a=(asd agh ijk)
$ echo "${a[@]^[!${a:0:1}]}"
asd agh Ijk
```

Comment: It is almost what I would have wanted(simulate to lower camel case in "one go"). Unfortunately the exception you mentioned would not work out..

Answer (score 1):

Not a double substitution, but a short solution:

To take advantage of `shift` we may use the positional parameters instead of an array.

```
set -- asd fgh ijk; 
b=$1; shift; printf '%s ' "$b" "${@^}"
```

Defining a function:

```
$ cc(){ local b=$1; shift; printf '%s ' "$b" "${@^}"; }
$ cc asd fgh ijk
asd Fgh Ijk
```

If you need the words as one long string, replace `'%s '` with `'%s'`:

```
$ cc(){ local b=$1; shift; printf '%s' "$b" "${@^}"; }
$ cc asd fgh ijk
asdFghIjk
```

Comment: @ASDFGHJKL A new approach to the problem. Quite simple IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Title case the whole string, then toggle the first character?

```
declare -c a
a=(asd agh ijk)
b="${a[0]~} ${a[@]:1}"
```

Comment: What does `declare -c` do? I can't find the documentation for it.

Comment: @BenjaminW. [Engages title case (eg "Capital Case").](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/declare.def#n208) See also `-l` and `-u`.

Comment: Those two are documented ;)

Comment: Beautiful, Thanks. Maybe `b="${a~} ${a[@]:1}"` is enough?.

Comment: @sorontar Only because skipping the index when expanding an array element defaults to the first element - adding the index keeps things more clear, in my opinion.